# Camera Sensor Driver for ov9281

Tags: camera, xilinx, device-driver, xilinx-ise, userspace

I am trying to write a bare-metal application to stream images on a VGA monitor using an ov9281 camera.
[This is my Hardware design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7PsD.png).
I have used the same design with the ov5640 camera (PCAM).
Until now I am able to configure ov5640 and steam data using the bare-metal application. I understand that the registers have to be configured the way shown below.

```
static u32  cfg_init [][2]  = {
//[7]=0 Software reset; [6]=1 Software power down; Default=0x02
{0x3008, 0x42},
//[1]=1 System input clock from PLL; Default read = 0x11
{0x3103, 0x03},
//[3:0]=0000 MD2P,MD2N,MCP,MCN input; Default=0x00
{0x3017, 0x00},
//[7:2]=000000 MD1P,MD1N, D3:0 input; Default=0x00
{0x3018, 0x00},
//[6:4]=001 PLL charge pump, [3:0]=1000 MIPI 8-bit mode
{0x3034, 0x18},
//PLL1 configuration
//[7:4]=0001 System clock divider /1, [3:0]=0001 Scale divider for MIPI /1
{0x3035, 0x11},
//[7:0]=56 PLL multiplier
{0x3036, 0x38},
//[4]=1 PLL root divider /2, [3:0]=1 PLL pre-divider /1
{0x3037, 0x11},
//[5:4]=00 PCLK root divider /1, [3:2]=00 SCLK2x root divider /1, [1:0]=01 SCLK root divider /2
{0x3108, 0x01},
//PLL2 configuration
//[5:4]=01 PRE_DIV_SP /1.5, [2]=1 R_DIV_SP /1, [1:0]=00 DIV12_SP /1
{0x303D, 0x10},
//[4:0]=11001 PLL2 multiplier DIV_CNT5B = 25
{0x303B, 0x19},

{0x3630, 0x2e},
{0x3631, 0x0e},
{0x3632, 0xe2},
{0x3633, 0x23},
{0x3621, 0xe0},
{0x3704, 0xa0},
{0x3703, 0x5a},
{0x3715, 0x78},
{0x3717, 0x01},
{0x370b, 0x60},
{0x3705, 0x1a},
{0x3905, 0x02},
{0x3906, 0x10},
{0x3901, 0x0a},
{0x3731, 0x02},
//VCM debug mode
{0x3600, 0x37},
{0x3601, 0x33},
//System control register changing not recommended
{0x302d, 0x60},
//??
{0x3620, 0x52},
{0x371b, 0x20},
//?? DVP
{0x471c, 0x50},

{0x3a13, 0x43},
{0x3a18, 0x00},
{0x3a19, 0xf8},
{0x3635, 0x13},
{0x3636, 0x06},
{0x3634, 0x44},
{0x3622, 0x01},
{0x3c01, 0x34},
{0x3c04, 0x28},
{0x3c05, 0x98},
{0x3c06, 0x00},
{0x3c07, 0x08},
{0x3c08, 0x00},
{0x3c09, 0x1c},
{0x3c0a, 0x9c},
{0x3c0b, 0x40},

//[7]=1 color bar enable, [3:2]=00 eight color bar
{0x503d, 0x00},
//[2]=1 ISP vflip, [1]=1 sensor vflip
{0x3820, 0x46},

//[7:5]=010 Two lane mode, [4]=0 MIPI HS TX no power down, [3]=0 MIPI LP RX no power down, [2]=1 MIPI enable, [1:0]=10 Debug mode; Default=0x58
{0x300e, 0x45},
//[5]=0 Clock free running, [4]=1 Send line short packet, [3]=0 Use lane1 as default, [2]=1 MIPI bus LP11 when no packet; Default=0x04
{0x4800, 0x14},
{0x302e, 0x08},
//[7:4]=0x3 YUV422, [3:0]=0x0 YUYV
//{0x4300, 0x30},
//[7:4]=0x6 RGB565, [3:0]=0x0 {b[4:0],g[5:3],g[2:0],r[4:0]}
{0x4300, 0x6f},
{0x501f, 0x01},

{0x4713, 0x03},
{0x4407, 0x04},
{0x440e, 0x00},
{0x460b, 0x35},
//[1]=0 DVP PCLK divider manual control by 0x3824[4:0]
{0x460c, 0x20},
//[4:0]=1 SCALE_DIV=INT(3824[4:0]/2)
{0x3824, 0x01},

//MIPI timing
//      {0x4805, 0x10}, //LPX global timing select=auto
//      {0x4818, 0x00}, //hs_prepare + hs_zero_min ns
//      {0x4819, 0x96},
//      {0x482A, 0x00}, //hs_prepare + hs_zero_min UI
//
//      {0x4824, 0x00}, //lpx_p_min ns
//      {0x4825, 0x32},
//      {0x4830, 0x00}, //lpx_p_min UI
//
//      {0x4826, 0x00}, //hs_prepare_min ns
//      {0x4827, 0x32},
//      {0x4831, 0x00}, //hs_prepare_min UI

//[7]=1 LENC correction enabled, [5]=1 RAW gamma enabled, [2]=1 Black pixel cancellation enabled, [1]=1 White pixel cancellation enabled, [0]=1 Color interpolation enabled
{0x5000, 0x07},
//[7]=0 Special digital effects, [5]=0 scaling, [2]=0 UV average disabled, [1]=1 Color matrix enabled, [0]=1 Auto white balance enabled
{0x5001, 0x03}};

    static u32  cfg_simple_awb[][2] = {
        // Disable Advanced AWB
        {0x518d ,0x00},
        {0x518f ,0x20},
        {0x518e ,0x00},
        {0x5190 ,0x20},
        {0x518b ,0x00},
        {0x518c ,0x00},
        {0x5187 ,0x10},
        {0x5188 ,0x10},
        {0x5189 ,0x40},
        {0x518a ,0x40},
        {0x5186 ,0x10},
        {0x5181 ,0x58},
        {0x5184 ,0x25},
        {0x5182 ,0x11},
    // Enable simple AWB
    {0x3406 ,0x00},
    {0x5183 ,0x80},
    {0x5191 ,0xff},
    {0x5192 ,0x00},
    {0x5001 ,0x03}
};


static u32  cfg_720p_60fps[][2] =
{//1280 x 720 binned, RAW10, MIPISCLK=280M, SCLK=56Mz, PCLK=56M
        //PLL1 configuration
        {0x3008, 0x42},
        //[7:4]=0010 System clock divider /2, [3:0]=0001 Scale divider for MIPI /1
        {0x3035, 0x21},
        //[7:0]=70 PLL multiplier
        {0x3036, 0x46},
        //[4]=0 PLL root divider /1, [3:0]=5 PLL pre-divider /1.5
        {0x3037, 0x05},
        //[5:4]=01 PCLK root divider /2, [3:2]=00 SCLK2x root divider /1, [1:0]=01 SCLK root divider /2
        {0x3108, 0x11},

        //[6:4]=001 PLL charge pump, [3:0]=1010 MIPI 10-bit mode
        {0x3034, 0x1A},

        //[3:0]=0 X address start high byte
        {0x3800, (0 >> 8) & 0x0F},
        //[7:0]=0 X address start low byte
        {0x3801, 0 & 0xFF},
        //[2:0]=0 Y address start high byte
        {0x3802, (8 >> 8) & 0x07},
        //[7:0]=0 Y address start low byte
        {0x3803, 8 & 0xFF},

        //[3:0] X address end high byte
        {0x3804, (2619 >> 8) & 0x0F},
        //[7:0] X address end low byte
        {0x3805, 2619 & 0xFF},
        //[2:0] Y address end high byte
        {0x3806, (1947 >> 8) & 0x07},
        //[7:0] Y address end low byte
        {0x3807, 1947 & 0xFF},

        //[3:0]=0 timing hoffset high byte
        {0x3810, (0 >> 8) & 0x0F},
        //[7:0]=0 timing hoffset low byte
        {0x3811, 0 & 0xFF},
        //[2:0]=0 timing voffset high byte
        {0x3812, (0 >> 8) & 0x07},
        //[7:0]=0 timing voffset low byte
        {0x3813, 0 & 0xFF},

        //[3:0] Output horizontal width high byte
        {0x3808, (1280 >> 8) & 0x0F},
        //[7:0] Output horizontal width low byte
        {0x3809, 1280 & 0xFF},
        //[2:0] Output vertical height high byte
        {0x380a, (720 >> 8) & 0x7F},
        //[7:0] Output vertical height low byte
        {0x380b, 720 & 0xFF},

        //HTS line exposure time in # of pixels
        {0x380c, (1896 >> 8) & 0x1F},
        {0x380d, 1896 & 0xFF},
        //VTS frame exposure time in # lines
        {0x380e, (984 >> 8) & 0xFF},
        {0x380f, 984 & 0xFF},

        //[7:4]=0x3 horizontal odd subsample increment, [3:0]=0x1 horizontal even subsample increment
        {0x3814, 0x31},
        //[7:4]=0x3 vertical odd subsample increment, [3:0]=0x1 vertical even subsample increment
        {0x3815, 0x31},

        //[2]=0 ISP mirror, [1]=0 sensor mirror, [0]=1 horizontal binning
        {0x3821, 0x01},

        //little MIPI shit: global timing unit, period of PCLK in ns * 2(depends on # of lanes)
        {0x4837, 36}, // 1/56M*2

        //Undocumented anti-green settings
        {0x3618, 0x00}, // Removes vertical lines appearing under bright light
        {0x3612, 0x59},
        {0x3708, 0x64},
        {0x3709, 0x52},
        {0x370c, 0x03},

        //[7:4]=0x0 Formatter RAW, [3:0]=0x0 BGBG/GRGR
        {0x4300, 0x00},
        //[2:0]=0x3 Format select ISP RAW (DPC)
        {0x501f, 0x03},
        {0x3008, 0x02},
    };

static u32  cfg_1080p_30fps[][2] =
{//1920 x 1080 @ 30fps, RAW10, MIPISCLK=672, SCLK=67.2MHz, PCLK=134.4M
        //PLL1 configuration
        {0x3008, 0x42},
        ///PLL1 configuration
        //[7:4]=0010 System clock divider /2, [3:0]=0001 Scale divider for MIPI /1
        {0x3035, 0x21}, // 30fps setting
        //[7:0]=105 PLL multiplier
        {0x3036, 0x69},
        //[4]=0 PLL root divider /1, [3:0]=5 PLL pre-divider /1.5
        {0x3037, 0x05},
        //[5:4]=01 PCLK root divider /2, [3:2]=00 SCLK2x root divider /1, [1:0]=01 SCLK root divider /2
        {0x3108, 0x11},

        //[6:4]=001 PLL charge pump, [3:0]=1010 MIPI 10-bit mode
        {0x3034, 0x1A},

        //[3:0]=0 X address start high byte
        {0x3800, (336 >> 8) & 0x0F},
        //[7:0]=0 X address start low byte
        {0x3801, 336 & 0xFF},
        //[2:0]=0 Y address start high byte
        {0x3802, (426 >> 8) & 0x07},
        //[7:0]=0 Y address start low byte
        {0x3803, 426 & 0xFF},

        //[3:0] X address end high byte
        {0x3804, (2287 >> 8) & 0x0F},
        //[7:0] X address end low byte
        {0x3805, 2287 & 0xFF},
        //[2:0] Y address end high byte
        {0x3806, (1529 >> 8) & 0x07},
        //[7:0] Y address end low byte
        {0x3807, 1529 & 0xFF},

        //[3:0]=0 timing hoffset high byte
        {0x3810, (16 >> 8) & 0x0F},
        //[7:0]=0 timing hoffset low byte
        {0x3811, 16 & 0xFF},
        //[2:0]=0 timing voffset high byte
        {0x3812, (12 >> 8) & 0x07},
        //[7:0]=0 timing voffset low byte
        {0x3813, 12 & 0xFF},

        //[3:0] Output horizontal width high byte
        {0x3808, (1920 >> 8) & 0x0F},
        //[7:0] Output horizontal width low byte
        {0x3809, 1920 & 0xFF},
        //[2:0] Output vertical height high byte
        {0x380a, (1080 >> 8) & 0x7F},
        //[7:0] Output vertical height low byte
        {0x380b, 1080 & 0xFF},

        //HTS line exposure time in # of pixels Tline=HTS/sclk
        {0x380c, (2500 >> 8) & 0x1F},
        {0x380d, 2500 & 0xFF},
        //VTS frame exposure time in # lines
        {0x380e, (1120 >> 8) & 0xFF},
        {0x380f, 1120 & 0xFF},

        //[7:4]=0x1 horizontal odd subsample increment, [3:0]=0x1 horizontal even subsample increment
        {0x3814, 0x11},
        //[7:4]=0x1 vertical odd subsample increment, [3:0]=0x1 vertical even subsample increment
        {0x3815, 0x11},

        //[2]=0 ISP mirror, [1]=0 sensor mirror, [0]=0 no horizontal binning
        {0x3821, 0x00},

        //little MIPI shit: global timing unit, period of PCLK in ns * 2(depends on # of lanes)
        {0x4837, 24}, // 1/84M*2

        //Undocumented anti-green settings
        {0x3618, 0x00}, // Removes vertical lines appearing under bright light
        {0x3612, 0x59},
        {0x3708, 0x64},
        {0x3709, 0x52},
        {0x370c, 0x03},

        //[7:4]=0x0 Formatter RAW, [3:0]=0x0 BGBG/GRGR
        {0x4300, 0x00},
        //[2:0]=0x3 Format select ISP RAW (DPC)
        {0x501f, 0x03},
        {0x3008, 0x02}

        /*[7:4]=0x0 Formatter RAW, [3:0]=0x0 BGBG/GRGR
        {0x4300, 0x00},
        //[2:0]=0x3 Format select ISP RAW (DPC)
        {0x501f, 0x03}*/
}
```

However this driver for ov5640 was availabe and I do not know how to write this for ov9281.

Could anybody please help me with that ?

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have asked this question on various forums and no help so far.
Thanks in Advance!